# How to solve the "inf" result in c++

Tags: c++

The output is infinte when I want to get the triangle area.
I want to get the triangle area only when the sum of two sides is bigger than the other side.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float tri_rib1;
    float tri_rib2;
    float tri_rib3;
    float tri_ribz;
    float tri_base= 0.5*tri_rib2;
    tri_ribz=sqrt((tri_rib1*tri_rib1)-(tri_base*tri_base)) ;
    float tri_area= 0.5*tri_ribz*tri_rib2;
    cout<<"\t This excercise calculates the area of a triangle only when the sum of two ribs is longer than the other one \n \n";
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib1: ";cin>>tri_rib1;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib2: ";cin>>tri_rib2;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib3: ";cin>>tri_rib3;
    if (tri_rib1+tri_rib2 > tri_rib3 || tri_rib2+tri_rib3 > tri_rib1 || tri_rib1+tri_rib3 > tri_rib2){
        cout<<"The area= "<<tri_area;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Sorry,This is not a triangle";
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the output is infinte " ?. Need to capture input before area calculation. i.e `cin>>` to be before using for calculation.

Comment: Initialise your variables to recognisable default values, then try again.

Comment: Move the `tri_base=` line and the `tri_ribz=...` line and the `tri_area=...` after the three lines `cin>>...`. Then try with initialised variables again.

Comment: I think you need to read up on the effect and useage of variable assignments. You seem to confuse them with establishing a equality relation, which is not the way C++ works.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you it works

Comment: Also, turn up the warning level on your compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using most of your variables before there is a meaningful value inside.
Initialise your variables to recognisable default values, this is a practice which will often help you to find problems from using uninitialised variables.

However, to get the intended values into the variables BEFORE they are used,
move the `tri_base=` line and the `tri_ribz=...` line and the `tri_area=...` after the three lines `cin>>....`. Because the three lines are what puts the desired values into the variables and the lines with the `=` then use those values to calculate meaningful things.

The true cause for the problem you are encountering might be a misunderstanding of the effects and their sequence of assignments to variables.
Understandably, a line like `tri_ribz=sqrt((tri_rib1*tri_rib1)-(tri_base*tri_base)) ;` looks misleadingly like setting up an equality realtion like in math, which then holds true for the rest of the program. But that is not the case.
Such a line only write the value calculated at the right of the `=` once into the variable on the left of `=`. But if you later change the variables used in the calculation, the value inside the variable on the left does NOT change.

So, if I am right in my assumption, I think you need to read up on the effect and useage of variable assignments. You seem to confuse them with establishing a equality relation, which is not the way C++ works.
The right way to do so might be to follow some tutorials on variables, assignments and multi-step calculations.

Or to put it more specific: Look for tutorials which contain several lines with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Following a suggestion of Yunnosh I did an exercise with lambda expressions (first example) and defines (at the end).

Perhaps a lambda comes conceptually close to your supposed original idea of what an assignment is: A permanent "living" relationship between variables, not a "frozen value" from a given point in the past.

I have never worked with lambdas in C++, so this is a first. From what I understand: The general idea is that a lambda is a kind of anonymous function. It can do something though that functions can't: It is able to access variables accessible in its scope. I think functions in the Algol/Pascal family, which are truly nested, can do that as well, but C/C++ functions cannot.

Lambdas are typically used ad-hoc, e.g. passed as an argument to a standard library algorithm. I'm using it here in a somewhat atypical fashion because I actually define variables which contain the lambdas. When it is defined, each lambda establishes a relationship with a *reference* to previously defined variables and defines a computing algorithm with these values. But like with a function definition, no computation is actually executed.

Resembling a function, a lambda is *callable*, i.e. each one defines an `operator()` which executes it like a function. This I use in the code below.

In order to demonstrate how the lambda returns different values when the referenced variables change their value I added a second input/output cycle. I also output the intermediate results.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float tri_rib1;
    float tri_rib2;
    float tri_rib3;

    //               | Uses capture by reference
    //               |                          | referenced variable defined outside the lambda 
    //               v                          v
    auto tri_base = [&]() { auto ret = 0.5 * tri_rib2; cout << "Computing base = "<< ret << endl; return ret; };
    auto tri_ribz = [&]() { auto ret = sqrt((tri_rib1 * tri_rib1) - (tri_base() * tri_base())); cout << "Computing ribz = "<< ret << endl; return ret; };
    auto tri_area = [&]() { auto ret = 0.5 * tri_ribz() * tri_rib2; cout << "Computing area = "<< ret << endl; return ret; };

    cout<<"\t This excercise calculates the area of a triangle only when the sum of two ribs is longer than the other one \n \n";
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib1: "; cin>>tri_rib1;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib2: "; cin>>tri_rib2;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib3: "; cin>>tri_rib3;

    if (       tri_rib1 + tri_rib2 > tri_rib3
            || tri_rib2 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib1 
            || tri_rib1 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib2 ) {
        cout<<"The area= " << tri_area();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Sorry,This is not a triangle";
    }

    cout<<"\tOK, another one:\n \n";
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib1: "; cin>>tri_rib1;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib2: "; cin>>tri_rib2;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib3: "; cin>>tri_rib3;

    if (       tri_rib1 + tri_rib2 > tri_rib3
            || tri_rib2 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib1 
            || tri_rib1 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib2 ) {
        cout<<"The area= " << tri_area();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Sorry,This is not a triangle";
    }
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o ref-capture ref-capture.cpp && ./ref-capture
         This excercise calculates the area of a triangle only when the sum of two ribs is longer than the other one

Enter the value of rib1: 1.4142
Enter the value of rib2: 1.4142
Enter the value of rib3: 2
The area= Computing base = 0.7071
Computing base = 0.7071
Computing ribz = 1.22473
Computing area = 0.866009
0.866009        OK, another one:

Enter the value of rib1: 2.8284
Enter the value of rib2: 2.8284
Enter the value of rib3: 4
The area= Computing base = 1.4142
Computing base = 1.4142
Computing ribz = 2.44947
Computing area = 3.46403
3.46403
```

---

Example with defines follows. A define is simple text replacement: The actual compiler only sees, as source code, what is on the right hand side of the define. Defines containing code are brittle (they rely on names over which they have no control) and of course not recommended, perhaps except when they transform a single definition into code containing the same variable name or string etc. in several places, which is then guaranteed to be identical, making maintenance easy. Anyway, here it is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float tri_rib1;
    float tri_rib2;
    float tri_rib3;

#    define tri_base (0.5 * tri_rib2)
#    define tri_ribz (sqrt(tri_rib1 * tri_rib1 - tri_base * tri_base))
#    define tri_area (0.5 * tri_ribz * tri_rib2)

    cout<<"\t This excercise calculates the area of a triangle only when the sum of two ribs is longer than the other one \n \n";
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib1: "; cin>>tri_rib1;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib2: "; cin>>tri_rib2;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib3: "; cin>>tri_rib3;

    if (       tri_rib1 + tri_rib2 > tri_rib3
            || tri_rib2 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib1 
            || tri_rib1 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib2 ) {
        cout<<"The area= " << tri_area;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Sorry,This is not a triangle";
    }

    cout<<"\tOK, another one:\n \n";
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib1: "; cin>>tri_rib1;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib2: "; cin>>tri_rib2;
    cout<<"Enter the value of rib3: "; cin>>tri_rib3;

    if (       tri_rib1 + tri_rib2 > tri_rib3
            || tri_rib2 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib1 
            || tri_rib1 + tri_rib3 > tri_rib2 ) {
        cout<<"The area= " << tri_area;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Sorry,This is not a triangle";
    }
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o ref-define ref-define.cpp && ./ref-define
         This excercise calculates the area of a triangle only when the sum of two ribs is longer than the other one

Enter the value of rib1: 1.4142
Enter the value of rib2: 1.4142
Enter the value of rib3: 2
The area= 0.866009      OK, another one:

Enter the value of rib1: 2.8284
Enter the value of rib2: 2.8284
Enter the value of rib3: 4
The area= 3.46403
```